# Arcgis Javascript Proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use proxy for arcgis.My proxy.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*" mustMatch="false">
    <serverUrls>
        <serverUrl url="http://myownservice.com.tr" matchAll="false"/>                 
        <serverUrl url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services" matchAll="false"/>
    </serverUrls>
</ProxyConfig>
```

and my js code :

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
    urlPrefix: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services",
    proxyUrl: "http://localhost/Dotnet/proxy.ashx"
});

urlUtils.addProxyRule({
    urlPrefix: "http://myownservice.com.tr",
    proxyUrl: "http://localhost/Dotnet/proxy.ashx"
});
```

When i execute project services.arcgis get proxy well.
Just like this :

```
http://localhost/Dotnet/proxy.ashx?http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tilemap/12/1528/2376/8/8
```

but my own services doesn't take proxy.

```
http://myownservice.com.tr:6080/arcgis/rest/info?f=json
```